# Undefined index: email_driver when the user pays via bank

Tags: php, laravel, email, payment, mailgun

Im getting this **message** when trying to **pay** via bank information in Laravel **4.2.** Sending emails with mailgun **works** fine, so I m wondering what could be the **reason** why this happens? My email **credentials** are listed in my enviroment file:

```
'email_driver'          => 'mailgun',
'email_smtp_host'       => 'smtp.mailgun.org',
'email_smtp_port'       =>  587,
'email_from_address'    => '.....',
'email_from_name'       => '.....',
'email_encryption'      => 'tls',
'email_username'        => 'postmaster@......mailgun.org',
'email_password'        => '.......',
'email_pretend'         =>  false
```

Would appreciate any help!

Comment: You need to post the code that you're using for the bank payments. Mailgun and bank processes usually don't have anything to do with the other.

Comment: Thanks! I ll make update on my question.